# JQuery-UI Draggable: dragged element size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to do the following: I have an icon on a page and when i drag it the icon changes. It has to not go beyond the containment area.

What I've tried is something like this:

```
$("#myElement").draggalble({
    containment: "#myContainer",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).attr("width", "20");
        $(this).attr("height", "20");
        $(this).attr("src", "newSource.png");
    }
});
```

The icon successfully changes and I can drag it.
The only problem is the new icon size. It is a little smaller than the original.
When I drag it near the boundaries of the container it stops too early, I can't reach container boundaries. Specifically I can't reach the upper and right boundaries but I can still reach the bottom and the left. I think this is because the draggable plugin calculates the icon limits using the size of the old icon.

Does anyone have some advice on how can I drag the new icon and reach the container boundaries?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the images are the same size you can just set the size with CSS and remove `$(this).attr('size', 'X');`.

Comment: Thank you for your adivice. The second image is a bit smaller. I've tried your advice but using .css instead of .attr doesn't change anything..

Comment: I meant you can set the size in your actual CSS file, not with javascript. That way the size will stay the same between the two images, no need to change size with javascript.

Comment: I have not been able to recreate this. Fiddle here trying to recreate this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/FA9dp/3/

Comment: @mccannf Broken for me in Chrome 23 on Windows 8.

Comment: @mccannf i tried your fiddle and it does recreate exactly the same scenario: i can't drag the new icon to the right and bottom borders. I've tested it on Chrome 23 and Firefox 17.

Comment: @qwerty the size needs to change, the new icon has to be smaller. Btw i also tried to change the size via css without using javascript but the behaviour is the same..

Comment: I added `width` and `height` declarations to @mccannf's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/FA9dp/3) and the icon doesn't shrink and reaches the boundary of the container. Using Chrome (23.0.1271.95).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, I had to create a container object based on the smaller picture's dimensions.

Using the following options - parameters are the container div, small picture width and small picture height respectively:

```
 containment: shrinkSize("#container",20,20),
```

and the function does the following:

```
function shrinkSize(frameId, smallerWidth, smallerHeight) {
    var frameOffset = $(frameId).offset(),
        frameHeight = $(frameId).height()-smallerWidth,
        frameWidth = $(frameId).width()-smallerHeight;

    return ([frameOffset.left, frameOffset.top, frameOffset.left+frameWidth, frameOffset.top+frameHeight]);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/rLmD3/6/).

P.S. in the fiddle, the image being dragged reverts to original size when dropped. If this is not the intended behavior, just remove the `stop` option (with function) from the `draggable` definition.